# Models from External package are showing in swagger docs

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am working on swagger documentation and added an external package "**NodaTime**" and used as type for my properties in models 
`public LocalDateTime Date { get; set; }`
and models from **NodaTime** package are showing in docs.
please see models in the screenshot, highlighted are from **NodaTime** package.
Why Swagger including it in the docs and how to exclude external package from docs.
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your swagger.json? My guess is that you are using those models in  the response of one of your actions

Comment: Also what are you using to generate the swagger documentation (Swashbuckle)?

Comment: yes Swashbuckle

Comment: @HelderSepu No i am not using those models i am sure, i am just using the types from this package nothing more.

Comment: If Swashbuckle is showing them that is because you are using them, directly or indirectly but you are using them, Can you share your swagger.json?

Comment: A minimal project reproducing your issue will be very helpful too!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i can't use the `DefaultModelExpandDepth(0);` because this will hide my own models, i am using as a type in models.
so, i used to check which types are coming from external package and excluded them like below.

Add **filter**

```
public class RemoveVerbsFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Definitions.Remove("LocalDateTime");
        swaggerDoc.Definitions.Remove("CalendarSystem");
        swaggerDoc.Definitions.Remove("Era");
        swaggerDoc.Definitions.Remove("LocalTime");
        swaggerDoc.Definitions.Remove("LocalDate");
    }
}
```

Add in startup class **ConfigureServices** method

```
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.DocumentFilter<RemoveVerbsFilter>();
        });
```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer based on the original question.

Comment: This answer no longer works in Swagger 5.x and above, as `SwaggerDocument` has been replaced by `OpenApiDocument` which doesn't define a Definitions property. I found that this worked in Swagger 6.x: `context.SchemaRepository.Schemas.Remove("LocalTime");`

Comment: Thank you Phil, I have been looking for such an answer / comment for my similar problem with a higher Swagger version, as you wrote.

Answer (score 9):

I'm guessing they are showing up because you are exposing an object that uses the NodaTime type. Swashbuckle / Swagger is showing the entire object graph... There is no way to turn off third party things like that if you models use those models. If you look at the code in the [library](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/41f7e3717dcffbc2984506674fe9cb681125bc25/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SchemaRegistry.cs) on github, you can see that Swashbuckle gives special treatment to several base class library primitives. The method is CreatePrimitiveSchema(), LocalDateTime is not in the case statement. Therefore, as a fix for this you could fork Swashbuckle and add in NodaTime types. This may not be worth it.

However, Swashbuckle allows you to turn off the model expansion. Below you can see how I have my Swashbuckle config setup. Setting DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1) will hide them.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, DataGraphContext db) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseSwagger();

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
            c.DefaultModelExpandDepth(0);
            c.DefaultModelsExpandDepth(-1);
        });

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseExceptionHandling();
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigins");
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

Comment: But this will hide my own models, i am using as a type in models. Like address in the top screenshot.

Comment: Correct, that is how swagger works, it shows the models from the object graph. Not showing the objects used by the object graph wouldn't make much sense. If you don't want to see third party models, don't use third party models in your API. Use DTO objects and map them back to other objects in your services. AutoMapper might be helpful in that case.

Comment: I am using the DateTime object and that is fine swagger is not digging into it, what is the difference between DateTime and NodaTime. what stops swagger to go to nested objects in DateTime?

Comment: That is interesting, the definition for DateTime and LocalDateTime look very similar. https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDateTime.html, https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/api/NodaTime.LocalDateTime.html Both are structs. However, it looks like Swashbuckle considers DateTime to be a primitive. 
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/41f7e3717dcffbc2984506674fe9cb681125bc25/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SchemaRegistry.cs